# Force a web page time out

Tags: .net-4.0, session-timeout

I have a web page that calls an external web service which returns some XML - calling it like this:

```
Resp = Req.GetResponse() *As HttpWebResponse
```

I put a try catch around this in order to capture application errors such as time out.  In order to test this, I entered the following in web.config:

```
 <system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="1" />
```

However this isn't working - I think this is 1 minute, not 1 second as I would like.  I also tried setting it t0 01.

Since I'm running in debug mode in VS 2010, I don't have IIS settings to mess with.

How can I test for exceptons?

Comment: all IIS does is alter the webconfig anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sessionState timeout is not what you are looking for I would look at setting the timeout on the HttpWebRequest.Timout method.

```
Req.Timeout = 1;  //Milliseconds
Resp = Req.GetResponse() *As HttpWebResponse
```

Comment: The SessionState is setting the timeout of the user session.  Not the timeout of the Request to the external web service.